# How to capture a list of specific type with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is there a way to capture a list of specific type using mockitos ArgumentCaptore. This doesn't work:

```
ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<SomeType>> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: I find that it's a terrible idea to use concrete list implementation here (`ArrayList`). You can always use `List` interface, and if you want represent the fact, that it's covariant, then you can use `extends`: `ArgumentCaptor<? extends List<SomeType>>`

Answer (score 676, accepted):

The nested generics-problem can be avoided with the [@Captor annotation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Captor.html):

```
public class Test{

    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<SomeType>> captor;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test 
    public void shouldDoStuffWithListValues() {
        //...
        verify(service).doStuff(captor.capture()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in the `@Before` method rather than using a runner that excludes the ability to use another runner. However, +1, thanks for pointing out the annotation.

Comment: Not sure this example is complete.  I get... Error:(240, 40) java: variable captor might not have been initialized i like tenshi's answer below

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and found this blog post which helped me a bit: http://blog.jdriven.com/2012/10/mockito-using-argumentcaptor-for-generic-typed-collections/. It includes a step to use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks after you've put the annotation on your class. One thing I noticed is you can't have it within a local variable.

Comment: @chamzz.dot ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<SomeType>> captor; is already capturing an array of "SomeType" <-- that is a specific type, isn't?

Comment: I usually prefer List instead of ArrayList in the Captor declaration: ArgumentCaptor<List<SomeType>> captor;

Comment: I had to use org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach instead of Before in my tests.

Comment: `initMocks(this)` should be replaced with `openMocks(this)`, as the first one ist deprecated

Comment: This worked for me with but in my implementation I use `@org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith(org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.class)` annotation at class level instead of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`.

Answer (score 178):

Yeah, this is a general generics problem, not mockito-specific.

There is no class object for `ArrayList<SomeType>`, and thus you can't type-safely pass such an object to a method requiring a `Class<ArrayList<SomeType>>`.

You can cast the object to the right type:

```
Class<ArrayList<SomeType>> listClass =
              (Class<ArrayList<SomeType>>)(Class)ArrayList.class;
ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<SomeType>> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(listClass);
```

This will give some warnings about unsafe casts, and of course your ArgumentCaptor can't really differentiate between `ArrayList<SomeType>` and `ArrayList<AnotherType>` without maybe inspecting the elements.

(As mentioned in the other answer, while this is a general generics problem, there is a Mockito-specific solution for the type-safety problem with the `@Captor` annotation. It still can't distinguish between an `ArrayList<SomeType>` and an `ArrayList<OtherType>`.)

#### Edit:

Take also a look at [tenshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576766/tenshi)'s comment. You can change the original code to this simplified version:

```
final ArgumentCaptor<List<SomeType>> listCaptor
        = ArgumentCaptor.forClass((Class) List.class);
```

Comment: The example you showed can be simplified, based on the fact that java makes type inference for the static method calls: `ArgumentCaptor<List<SimeType>> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass((Class) List.class);`

Comment: To disable the _uses unchecked or unsafe operations_ warning, use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation above the argument captor definition line. Also, casting to `Class` is redundant.

Comment: The casting to `Class` is not redundant in my tests.

Answer (score 24):

If you're not afraid of old java-style (non type safe generic) semantics, this also works and is simple'ish:

```
ArgumentCaptor<List> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
verify(subject).method(argument.capture()); // run your code
List<SomeType> list = argument.getValue(); // first captured List, etc.
```

Comment: You can add @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") before the declaration to disable warnings.

Answer (score 9):

```
List<String> mockedList = mock(List.class);

List<String> l = new ArrayList();
l.add("someElement");

mockedList.addAll(l);

ArgumentCaptor<List> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

verify(mockedList).addAll(argumentCaptor.capture());

List<String> capturedArgument = argumentCaptor.<List<String>>getValue();

assertThat(capturedArgument, hasItem("someElement"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on @tenshi's and @pkalinow's comments (also kudos to @rogerdpack), the following is a simple solution for creating a list argument captor that also disables the *"uses unchecked or unsafe operations"* warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final ArgumentCaptor<List<SomeType>> someTypeListArgumentCaptor =
    ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
```

Full example [here](https://gitlab.com/mrts/mockito-list-argumentcaptor-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/ArgumentCaptorTest.java) and corresponding passing CI build and test run [here](https://gitlab.com/mrts/mockito-list-argumentcaptor-example/-/jobs/60445359).

Our team has been using this for some time in our unit tests and this looks like the most straightforward solution for us.

Answer (score 3):

For an earlier version of junit, you can do

```
Class<Map<String, String>> mapClass = (Class) Map.class;
ArgumentCaptor<Map<String, String>> mapCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(mapClass);
```

Comment: This just results in a different Unchecked assignment warning.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with testing activity in my Android app. I used `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` didn't work.
I solved this issue with another class with respectively field. For example:

```
class CaptorHolder {

        @Captor
        ArgumentCaptor<Callback<AuthResponse>> captor;

        public CaptorHolder() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    }
```

Then, in activity test method:

```
HubstaffService hubstaffService = mock(HubstaffService.class);
fragment.setHubstaffService(hubstaffService);

CaptorHolder captorHolder = new CaptorHolder();
ArgumentCaptor<Callback<AuthResponse>> captor = captorHolder.captor;

onView(withId(R.id.signInBtn))
        .perform(click());

verify(hubstaffService).authorize(anyString(), anyString(), captor.capture());
Callback<AuthResponse> callback = captor.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue in Mockito's GitHub](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/565) about this exact problem.

I have found a simple workaround that does not force you to use annotations in your tests:

```java
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public final class MockitoCaptorExtensions {

    public static <T> ArgumentCaptor<T> captorFor(final CaptorTypeReference<T> argumentTypeReference) {
        return new CaptorContainer<T>().captor;
    }

    public static <T> ArgumentCaptor<T> captorFor(final Class<T> argumentClass) {
        return ArgumentCaptor.forClass(argumentClass);
    }

    public interface CaptorTypeReference<T> {

        static <T> CaptorTypeReference<T> genericType() {
            return new CaptorTypeReference<T>() {
            };
        }

        default T nullOfGenericType() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static final class CaptorContainer<T> {

        @Captor
        private ArgumentCaptor<T> captor;

        private CaptorContainer() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

    }

}
```

What happens here is that we create a new class *with* the `@Captor` annotation and inject the captor into it. Then we just extract the captor and return it from our static method.

In your test you can use it like so:

```java
ArgumentCaptor<Supplier<Set<List<Object>>>> fancyCaptor = captorFor(genericType());
```

Or with syntax that resembles Jackson's `TypeReference`:

```java
ArgumentCaptor<Supplier<Set<List<Object>>>> fancyCaptor = captorFor(
    new CaptorTypeReference<Supplier<Set<List<Object>>>>() {
    }
);
```

It works, because Mockito doesn't actually need any type information (unlike serializers, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Since Mockito 5.3.0 you can circumvent that problem with the `assertArg` matcher.[1](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification_with_assertions)

Assuming you want to do assertions on a method with signature

```java
interface MyInterface {
    MyResultType calculateSomething(List<MyType> aList)
}
```

you can just call (using AssertJ here)

```java
verify(myInterfaceMock).calculateSomething(
  assertArg(theList -> assertThat(theList)
    //inside here theList has the correct type
    .isNotNull()
    .isNotEmpty()
  )
);
```

For readability i prefer to put the assertions into a variable.

```java
final Consumer<? extends List<MyType>> myListAssertions = theList -> 
  assertThat(theList)
    .isNotNull()
    .isNotEmpty();

verify(myInterfaceMock).calculateSomething( assertArg(myListAssertions) );
```

This works well, with failed assertions pointing to the correct line where the actual assertion is defined.