# Specify the class of a generic interface to mock

Tags: java, generics, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to capture an argument using Mockito.  This argument is of type `List< MyClass >`.  But I can't find the proper syntax to specify it.

I *can* do this:

```
ArgumentCaptor< MyClass > captor = 
   ArgumentCaptor.forClass( MyClass.class );
```

But I don't get *this* to compile:

```
ArgumentCaptor< List<MyClass> > captor = 
   ArgumentCaptor.forClass( List<MyClass>.class );
```

Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture a list of specific type with mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606541/how-to-capture-a-list-of-specific-type-with-mockito)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, `.class` will only return the `Class<List>` object, where `List` is a rawtype. The implementation isn't perfect, and nested type information can't be obtained using `.class`. Something like `List<Foo>.class` is invalid syntax because no such `Class<List<Foo>>` object exists anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the implementation isn't perfect'?

Comment: I was referring to the language's implementation of generics.

Comment: :) I can nothing but agree with that ('ve been spoiled by C++ I guess)

Comment: @eskimo - wait, so is the `Class` object needed or not? I don't have experience with mockito, just generics.

Answer (score 15):

It should work using the [`@Captor`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Captor.html) annotation:

```
@Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<SomeType>> captor;
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me. Note that a 'MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);' is needed. (see also http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Captor.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because Java doesn't determine the type of a parametreized class statically.

The same way this does not compile:

```
Class<?> c1 = ArrayList<String>.class;
```

And this neither as on top of the type resolution issue `List` is an interface:

```
Class<?> c2 = List<String>.class;
```

But this does compile, and you can probably do something similar:

```
public class MyList implements List<String> {
    ... the List's methods to implement ...
}

// and later in the code:

Class<?> c3 = MyList.class;
```