# Mockito ArgumentCaptor for Optional arguments

Tags: java, mockito

Have a method in accountHandler class with following signature

```
public void processMessage(String accountId, 
Metrics metrics, 
Optional<ZonedDateTime> parsedDatetime) {

        // do something 
}
```

In the test, if I want to use argument captor, how do I define it?

Tried the following and it didn't work as expected.

```
ArgumentCaptor<ZonedDateTime> timeCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ZonedDateTime.class);
```

What is the syntax to make this optional with argcaptor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture a list of specific type with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606541/how-to-capture-a-list-of-specific-type-with-mockito)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below case is for a method signature of:

```
public void processMessage(Optional<ZonedDateTime> parsedDatetime) {
```

Since I don't know which `Meteric` class is used, I also hope AccountHandler class exists.

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void withValue() {
    ArgumentCaptor<Optional<ZonedDateTime>> timeCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Optional.class);
    AccountHandler accountHandler = mock(AccountHandler.class);

    Optional<ZonedDateTime> input = Optional.of(ZonedDateTime.now());
    accountHandler.processMessage(input);

    verify(accountHandler).processMessage(timeCaptor.capture());

    Optional<ZonedDateTime> optional = timeCaptor.getValue();
    assertTrue(optional.isPresent());
    assertNotNull(optional.get());
}

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void nullOptional() {
    ArgumentCaptor<Optional<ZonedDateTime>> timeCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Optional.class);
    AccountHandler accountHandler = mock(AccountHandler.class);

    Optional<ZonedDateTime> input = null;
    accountHandler.processMessage(input);

    verify(accountHandler).processMessage(timeCaptor.capture());

    Optional<ZonedDateTime> optional = timeCaptor.getValue();
    assertNull(optional);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) I was not sure of the part inside .forClass(). It makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606541/how-to-capture-a-list-of-specific-type-with-mockito), use @Captor annotation:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Optional<ZonedDateTime>> captor;
```