# Mockito: verify parameter without having to cast it

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, hamcrest

I have a service class with the following method:

```
void doSomething(List<String> list)
```

I mock this class and I want to verify that a list which is passed as a parameter has only one element. I do it like this:

```
verify(myService).doSomething((List<String>) argThat(hasSize(1))))
```

As you see **I have to cast the argument to `List<String>`**  otherwise it doesn't get compiled:

```
incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
  inferred: java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.Object>
  upper bound(s): java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.lang.Object
```

**Question:** How can I verify the call without casting? I want to keep things simple, readable and elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer this solution:

```
final ArgumentCaptor<List> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

verify(myService).doSomething(argumentCaptor.capture());

assertThat(argumentCaptor.getValue().size()).isEqualTo(1);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had to rework your code a bit as the way you posted it it doesn't get compiled - it requites `ArgumentCaptor<List<String>>` and I had to do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655702/2065796.  I'll accept your answer later if there is no better answer. Although it works it is still quite complex, a code that uses combination of matchers would have been shorter and clearer.